# How to check Similarity of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

I am given three $n\times n$ matrix $A$,$B$ & $C$ and there exists a non singular matrix such that $$P^{-1}BP=A$$ . Now If $A$ and $B$ are similar and $B$ and $C$ are similar will $AB$ and $BC$ will be similar ? or A and C will be similar?

using condition in questions I assumed $$Q^{-1}CQ=B$$ and then substituing it given equation
I get $$(PQ)^{-1}C(PQ)=A$$ which tells us that $A$ is similar to $C$ but what about $AB$ and $BC$ ? was my approach correct which gave me $A$ is similar to $C$?

Comment: $$A\cdot B = \left(P^{-1}BP\right)\cdot\left(Q^{-1}CQ\right) = P^{-1}B\left(PQ^{-1}\right)CQ$$
That means $AB$ and $BC$ are not similar and can only be similar iff $P = Q = R \text{ (say)}$. In that case, $AB = R^{-1}BCR$

Comment: hmm , that answers the question

Comment: Yeah, I left in the comments because I don't feel this question deserves a real answer (no offence). I don't want easy points. In the future, please come on over to the math chat room for trivialities such as this.